# Google Chart hAxis Title

Tags: google-visualization

```
options: {"title":"Overall Stats","height":230,"legend":{"position":"in"},"hAxis":{"title":"Division"}},
```

I have this as my options for my google column chart but this displays "Division" on both my vertical and horizontal axis and removes all the labels on the hAxis. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I increased the height to show the horizontal labels again but it still displays the title on both axes

Answer (score 0):

is there more you can share?

seems to work fine here...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Energy Level');
    data.addRows([
      [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1, .25],
      [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2, .5],
      [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3, 1],
      [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4, 2.25],
      [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5, 2.25],
      [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6, 3],
      [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7, 4],
      [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8, 5.25],
      [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9, 7.5],
      [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10, 10],
    ]);

    new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'ColumnChart',
      containerId: 'chart_div',
      dataTable: data,
      options: {"title":"Overall Stats","height":230,"legend":{"position":"in"},"hAxis":{"title":"Division"}}
    }).draw();
  },
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've been trying for 3 days now and I still can't make it work. Perhaps the only thing I'm doing differently is I'm using a method called OnPrepareChart in a PHP generator which creates PHP pages based on mySQL data. This generator has a built in chart creator and if I want more customization I have to enter code manually using the method which is in PHP. From what I've read  the way to enter the hAxis title for example is `'hAxis' => array('title' => "Division"),` which then creates JS code like the one I put in the question

Comment: check the reference for [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) -- you can add labels back with `hAxis.ticks` or in your case `'hAxis' => array('ticks' => array(...))`